# FPDF - SetFillColor inside cell

Tags: javascript, php, html, fpdf

I have the need to create the cell with background color, but I was using the example:

```html
$pdf->SetFillColor(135,206,235);
$pdf->Rect(9, 52, 190, 7, 'F');
```

the problem with this example is that if I get a larger than expected number of lines, it does not usually fit as it is, so how can I define the color of the cell I'm using without putting XY in its location? it's possible?
Original Code:

```html
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(96 ,10,'RLT Resume',0,0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using this code i was able to fix my problem, the terms was bad on start:

```html
$pdf->SetFont('PetitaBold','',12);
$pdf->SetFillColor(70,130,180);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(25,25,12);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
```